# Why pytest execute functions on import

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following structure:

```
main/
|-- __init__.py
|-- foo.py
|-- bar.py
|-- tests/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_foo.py
    |-- test_bar.py
```

inside `test_foo.py` I am importing some packages (e.g. `os`, `sys`), I also import a helper function from `foo.py`:

```
from main.foo import testAllLevels
```

When I try to run tests from `main/`:

```
$ pytest tests/
```

I see that the function `testAllLevels` was also collected and run as a test and (obiously) failed. My question is how can I skip this function from test discovery?

Comment: try decorating the function with `@pytest.mark.skip`

Comment: Is it really called `testAllLevels`?  According to [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery), pytest should only collect functions whose name begins with `test_`.

Comment: @mangoHero1 when I mark the function in `foo.py` it skips all the tests in `test_foo.py`.

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, that's weird. I even tried to use regex and running `pytest tests/test_foo.py` explicitly, it still execute `testAllLevels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent `testAllLevels` from being collected as a test, you have to create a file called `pytest.ini` and put it either inside `main` or `tests` folder.

The content of `pytest.ini` should be something like this:

```
[pytest]
python_functions=test_
```

Note that this will also mean that all your test functions must have a prefix of `test_` from now on. The default behaviour of `pytest` is to collect functions with `test` (not `test_`) prefix.

To answer the question about `why functions are run on import?`, try the following experiment. In your `test_foo.py` add one line to get an internal reference to the `test_foo.py` module itself.

```
from main.foo import testAllLevels
reference_to_current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Then in the same module, create a test case that looks like this:

```
def test_01():
    print(dir(reference_to_current_module))
    reference_to_current_module.testAllLevels()
```

The output from the `dir()` will show you that `testAllLevels` has become a legitimate function belonging to `test_foo.py` after the import statement is executed. This has been verified by invoking the function through the reference to `test_foo.py`. I think it has been collected by pytest because it's a function "*belonging to*" a test module and its function name has a `test` prefix.

Comment: Great, that worked. Still would be interesting to know why functions are run on import, because for me it doesn't seem intuitive

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer to include what I believe makes pytest collect the imported function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change

```
from main.foo import testAllLevels
```

to

```
from main import foo
```

And then call it with `foo.testAllLevels`. Like that `testAllLevels` is not run as a test.

Something tells me that it's not the optimal solution. So the question is still open. If someone knows a reason for this behavior that would help a lot.